# Cart calculations in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm just starting out with AngularJS attempting to build a shopping cart.

Below is my code.

**Items.html**

```
<li id="{{item.id}}" ng-click="addItem(item)" class="menu-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
<span class="list-item-inner">
<span class="item-content">
<span class="vc-outer">
<span class="vc-inner">
<span class="list-item-title" style="color: #3F4B56; font-size: 1.1rem;" 
ng-bind="item.name">
</span>

<span class="list-item-description" style="font-size: 0.9rem; color: #6B7781;" ng-bind="item.description">
</span>
</span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
<span class="item-price">
<span class="vc-outer">
<span class="vc-inner no-wrap" 
ng-bind="'&#8358;' + (item.price)"></span>
</span>
    </span>
<span class="item-add"></span>

</li>
```

**Cart.html**

```
<li class="has-counter order-item" ng-class="{'has-modifier' : cart.length}" ng-repeat="item in cart">
    <div class="counter-control-vertical is-editable">
        <div class="controls"> <a href="" class="control ctrl-up" ng-click="incQty(item)" style="text-decoration: none;">
    +
    </a>
 <a href="" class="control ctrl-down" ng-click="decQty(item)" style="text-decoration: none;">
    –
    </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="oi-inner">
        <div class="oi-details" ng-click="editModifiers(item)">
            <div class="oi-quantity" ng-bind="(item.count) +'x'"></div>
            <div class="oi-title" ng-bind="item.name"></div>
            <div class="oi-modifiers"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="oi-price" ng-bind="'&#8358;' + (item.price)"></div> <a href="" ng-click="deleteItem(item)" class="oi-remove" style="text-decoration: none;">×</a>

    </div>
</li>
```

**Cart.js**

```
// Array containing my items.
$scope.itemData = <? php echo json_encode($item_array); ?> ;
$scope.cart = [];

$scope.deleteItem = function (item) {
    var cart = $scope.cart;
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match.count > 0) {
        cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item));
        return;
    }
}

$scope.addItem = function (item) {
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match) {
        match.count += 1;
        return;
    }
    var itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
    itemToAdd.count = 1;
    $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
}

$scope.incQty = function (item) {
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match) {
        match.count += 1;
        return;
    }
}

$scope.decQty = function (item) {
    var cart = $scope.cart;
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match.count > 1) {
        match.count -= 1;
        return;
    }
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
}
```

At the moment I can add, remove, increment and decrement items in the `cart` array and display them in realtime. But the price does not change based on qty.

My question is;

1. How can I calculate and display price based on qty of an item in `cart`?
2. How do I calculate total price of all the items in the `cart` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `ng-bind="item.price * item.count"`
2. I would call a function (witch calculates the total price) every time you change the cart and store the result in an new variable.

   ```
   $scope.calcTotal = function() {
       var total=0;
       for (var i = 0, max = $scope.cart.length; i < max; i++) {
           total += $scope.cart[i].price * $scope.cart[i].count;
       }   
       $scope.total = total;
   }
   ```

Comment: Answer 1 works. Thanks.
How do I bind your answer 2?
`ng-bind="calcTotal()"`?

Comment: no, we stored the result in $scope.total, so you have to bind $scope total: `ng-bind="total"` and you have to execute the function every time you change the cart.

Comment: Sorry just figured. If I'm already using `ng-click` to chnage the cart variables where do I implement the `calcTotal` function?

Comment: You can do it also in the `ng-click` `ng-click="addItem(item); calcTotal();"`  or you call it in your functions.